git: add uncompressed pdf file
I think I have one of the rare cases where I want to add a PDF file into a git repository.
In fact I have two cases:

I have no source PDF
I do have a source but I need the created PDF in a testcase.

Of course, this is expensive.
Now I think about adding the file uncompressed.
That way I can diff.
Although the initial version is expensive,
I think not more expensive than if compressed,
as far as I understand, further versions are less expensive,
because the PDF changes only in detail, mostly textual.
My question is twofold:

does my idea make sense?
if so, how can I make git uncompress when checking in
and compress again when checking out?


I think the actual solution to this is to look into the git-lfs tool to see if that fulfils your needs, its designed to allow you to store large binary files in git without them directly being in the directory - this is probably the way to go.
You can make git un/compress on check in/out using a tool know as a filter, but git will compress older content as part of it's routine house keeping.

try adding
*.pdf filter=compresspdf

in .gitattributes file
then change git config like this
$git config filter.compresspdf.clean "gzip"
$git config filter.compresspdf.smudge "gzip -d"

after you do it check with
git config --list | grep filter

output should be similar to
filter.compresspdf.clean=gzip
filter.compresspdf.smudge=gzip -d

